SwiftUI MVVM I don't know why it's not being redrawn
I manage the model as an array in viewModel and change the model's properties.
I don't know why the view doesn't change as the model's properties change.
I would appreciate your advice and feedback.
Here is the code:
model
class RoutineUnit: Identifiable, Equatable {
    
    static func == (lhs: RoutineUnit, rhs: RoutineUnit) -> Bool {
        return lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
    
    
    let id: String
    var title: String
    var isSelected: Bool
    var targetTask: RoutineUnitTask
    var tags: [RoutineUnitTag?]
    var tipComment: String
}

viewModel
class RoutineDetailViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var routineUnits: [RoutineUnit]

 func toggleSelection(for unitID: String) {
        if let index = routineUnits.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == unitID }) {
             routineUnits[index].isSelected.toggle()
        }
    }

}

view
struct RoutineUnitView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: RoutineDetailViewModel
    
    var unitID: String
    
    var body: some View {
        if let routineUnit = viewModel.getRoutineUnitByID(unitID) {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                .fill(Color.white)
                .overlay {
                   ...
                }
                .frame(height: 84)
                .onTapGesture {
                    withAnimation(.spring) {
                        if(viewModel.isEditingEnabled) {
                            viewModel.toggleSelection(for: unitID)
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}

viewModel.toggleSelection(for: unitID)Even though it is obviously running, the view is not redrawn. Maybe I don't understand mvvm?

View redraws its part, which depend on @Published properties of an @ObservedObject. Judging from your code, there's only one—routineUnits, and RoutineUnitView doesn't use it. (Methods are methods and only called, when they are called—their hypothetical results are not observed.)

Is isSelected really something that defines the model, isn't that a state that belongs in the view or the view model instead as a selection property that holds the selected RoutineUnit (if any)?

selection should be in @State, not ObservedObject that's for model data.

Get rid of the Equatable implementation you are literally telling SwiftUI to only redraw if the Id changes


Maybe I don't understand mvvm?

Your misunderstanding is not with MVVM, but how SwiftUI and state changes work.
All a Published property wrapper does is call the objectWillChange publisher of an ObservedObject in the willSet Handler.
This is all well documented by Apple. I recommend watching the related WWDC videos like Demystify SwiftUI.
Changing the property of an element in a Swift array does not call the willSet handler of the array itself.
In your case changing the isSelected property of a RoutineUnit does not change the routineUnits array or your RoutineDetailViewModel.
And since the willSet handler is not called, no event is emitted by the objectWillChange publisher and no SwiftUI re-layout / state update is triggered.
In other words, with a Published property wrapper you do not automatically get a “deep observation” of a property. Of course, this also applies to collection properties and their elements.
There are several ways to achieve what you want.
If your app does not require support for iOS versions prior to iOS 17, you can migrate to the Observable macro, which supports collections and the kind of deep observation you're trying to use.
Otherwise you will have to change your state handling or your data/view modeling.
You could also manually trigger the objectWillChange publisher in your toggleSelection method, but that would not be an ideal solution.
If you want changes to a RoutineUnit model in SwiftUI to result in a state change, they themselves must fulfill the ObservableObject protocol and you should have a separate view for a single RoutineUnit object.
Something like this:
final class RoutineUnit: Identifiable, Equatable, ObservableObject {
   // ...
}

struct RoutineUnitView: View {
    @ObservedObject var routineUnit: RoutineUnit

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("title: \(routineUnit.title)")

            if routineUnit.isSelected {
                // ...
            }
        }
    }
}

struct RoutineUnitListView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: RoutineDetailViewModel

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(viewModel.routineUnits) { unit in
                RoutineUnitView(routineUnit: unit)
            }            
        }
    }
}

I hope you understand the idea, i.e. one view/model for the list, one view/model for each detailed view.
This allows you to change the list as a whole and also the individual elements of the collection.

Thank you for your comment.  @Published var routineUnits: If defined as [RoutineUnit], objectWillChange is called when adding, updating, or deleting an array, right?

@CookKim yes, a Published array will call willSet when you add, delete or replace an element since Array is a value type. And since willSet is called, the publisher is also called.


Updated after @loremipsum comment

Look, MVVM means that you have the ViewModel and View. View subscribe on ViewModel updates/changes.
In you example:

You should have container View, that show UI according to viewModel items

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = RoutineDetailViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        List($viewModel.routineUnits) { unit in
            RoutineUnitView(unit: unit)
        }
    }
}


ViewModel simple example with data-mock

class RoutineDetailViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var routineUnits: [RoutineUnit] = []
    
    init() {
        routineUnits = [
            .init(id: "1", isSelected: false),
            .init(id: "12", isSelected: false),
            .init(id: "123", isSelected: false),
            .init(id: "1234", isSelected: false),
            .init(id: "12345", isSelected: false),
            .init(id: "123456", isSelected: false),
            .init(id: "1234567", isSelected: false),
            .init(id: "12345678", isSelected: false)
        ]
    }
}


You pass viewModel item entity to subview where you can modify it later

struct RoutineUnitView: View {
    @Binding var unit: RoutineUnit
    var body: some View {
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
            .fill(unit.isSelected ? .green :.white)
            .frame(height: 84)
            .overlay {
                VStack {
                    Text(unit.id)
                }
            }
            .onTapGesture {
                withAnimation {
                    unit.isSelected = true
                }
            }
    }
}

Also want no notice that is better to create Model as Struct( not class object). In yours initial code RoutineUnit is class
struct RoutineUnit: Identifiable {
    var id: String
    var isSelected: Bool
}

To read more about MVVM in SwiftUI you can visit:

https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/introducing-mvvm-into-your-swiftui-project


You should review the tutorials yourself, you are misusing both ObservedObject and State. You can also review the documentation for both

@loremipsum thanks for you comment. I did make a mistake. I've updated my answer with another approach "@StateObject" for storing ViewModel instance and "@Binding" for passing objects, that can be modified when interacting with List item.
